# How can I create this menu button in Javafx?

Tags: user-interface, javafx

[image: Image showing the menu button I want to implement on my project]

I'm working on a college project, and a I would like to create menu button to allow the users to decide whether to search by id or search by date, but I cannot find out how, or if it's even possible.

I would really appreciate if you could tell me if it is possible to create such a button as displayed in the image within the black circle, and how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following code:

```
        CheckMenuItem checkMenuItem1 = new CheckMenuItem("ID Search");
        CheckMenuItem checkMenuItem2 = new CheckMenuItem("Date Search");
        MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton();
        menuButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("path.fileExtension").toExternalForm())));
        menuButton.getItems().addAll(checkMenuItem1,checkMenuItem2);
```

Alternatively, you can use `CustomMenuItem`:

```
        CustomMenuItem idItem = new CustomMenuItem(new CheckBox("ID Search"));
        CustomMenuItem dateItem = new CustomMenuItem(new CheckBox("Date Search"));
        MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton();
        menuButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("path.fileExtension").toExternalForm())));
        menuButton.getItems().addAll(idItem,dateItem)
```

**Update:**
If The 2 search types should be mutually exclusive, you can replace `CheckMenuItem` by `RadioMenuItem`:

```
        RadioMenuItem radioMenuItem1 = new RadioMenuItem("ID Search");
        RadioMenuItem radioMenuItem2 = new RadioMenuItem("Date Search");
        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        toggleGroup.getToggles().addAll(radioMenuItem1, radioMenuItem2);
```

Comment: The 2 search types should be mutually exclusive. Namely they cannot be selected at the same time. Maybe RadioMenuItem?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple menu, create on your own the icon (cutting that from the screenshot for example) and adding it to your menu. I think it works.